# XPath expression for disabled input in IE7. Testing with Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

My problem is very simple. I'm writing a Selenium test that MUST work with IE7. I have a HTML table with couple of rows and 3 columns:

Column 1 - contains a check box

Column 2 - contains a link

Column 3 - contains some free text

One (and ONLY one) of the checkboxes in the table is disabled. My task is to locate and click the link next to the disabled checkbox (on the row of the disabled checkbox). In FireFox this simple XPath expressions work  fine:

```
//tr/td/input[@disabled]/../../td[2]/a

//tr/td/input[@disabled='disabled']/../../td[2]/a
```

But in IE7 the first expression clicks the top row no matter if the checkbox is enabled or disabled and the second one does not work.

Since the HTML document is very long I'm putting the important part below (as shown in FF):

```
<tr>
    <td class="table_detail w e s center">
        <input name="Delete_kG0KCgAMniwAAAEsxxgeUH0G" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
        <a href="..." class="table_detail_link">000000</a>
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
        some text
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="table_detail w e s center">
        <input name="Delete_hooKCgAMi5AAAAEsFnQeUH0G" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
        <a href="..." class="table_detail_link">111111</a>
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
          &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="table_detail w e s center">
        <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
        <a href="..." class="table_detail_link">400086</a>
    </td>
    <td class="table_detail e s">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

The last link should be clicked:

```
<a href="..." class="table_detail_link">400086</a>
```

We use the Java Selenium API in JUnit 3 tests. The test is something like:

```
public void testSomething()
{
   ...
   selenium.click("//tr/td/input[@disabled]/../../td[2]/a");

   //wait to load and then test something on the page that is opened.
   ...
}
```

This works in FF but not in IE7. In IE7 it clicks the link on the first row as if disabled is ignored. It also evaluates correct in XPather (FF plugin).

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: @user520359: This may have nothing to do with XPath. Did you check that those expressions do select the correct element? I don't know if Selenium works with the source document or the built DOM... (in the case of forms and tables the browser could be adding some anonymous elements)

Comment: Was it disabled by script? Most attributes are supposed to reflect the JS field, but perhaps IE doesn't reflect @disabled. You may need to do iterate in JS using getEval instead.

Comment: Please, provide the (x)HTML document and indicate which exactly node is to be selected. Without this information this isn't a question at all!

Comment: Hello, Dimitre. You are completely right. The post had been edited to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I was able to resolve the problem by using a DOM locator. Unfortunately it looks as ugly as:

```
dom=function getLinkNextToDisabled() 
{
    var addressesTable = document.getElementsByName('AddressList')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var inputs = addressesTable.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputs[i].disabled) 
        {
            return inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        }
    }
};
getLinkNextToDisabled();
```

Unfortunately code like this makes me sad, so I'm still open for any XPath solution that will work in IE7.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You have shown the HTML in FireFox, but you haven't shown the HTML in IE, is it the same?

Based upon the information provided I would use this locator:

```
//tr[td/input[@disabled='disabled']]/td/a
```

This finds a row that has a cell that contains a disabled input element, and then locates the cell that has an achor and pinpoints the anchor.

However as I cannot see the HTML markup in IE I have no idea if this is valid or not